# How do I send a message to my socket.io websocket from the command line in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, websocket, socket.io

Is it possible to **send a [socket.io](http://socket.io/) message** to my **localhost server** (node) using the command line in linux?

My socket.io code looks like this:

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var socket;

socket = io.listen(server, {log: false});
server.listen(8081);

socket.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('message', function (data) 
  {
    console.log("Received socket message from GUI: "+data);
  }
});
```

I'd like to send a socket.io message that looks like this: `"testControl,loadModels,start"` which then triggers some server side logic. Is this possible?

I came across [websocketd](http://websocketd.com/) which seems promising, but it *creates* a websocket in linux, I just want to *send* a message to an *existing* websocket.

*Version Info:*

- Node Version:  v0.10.42
- Socket.IO Version:  1.3.4
- Express Version:  4.12.0

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can write a simple client like this (let's name it `client` with no extension):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3000');
const someDelay = 10;
socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('connected...');
    if (process.argv[2] && process.argv[3]) {
        console.log('sending ' + process.argv[2] + ': ' + process.argv[3]);
        socket.emit(process.argv[2], process.argv[3]);
        setTimeout(() => {
            process.exit(0);  
        }, someDelay);
    } else {
        console.log('usage: ./client.js <event> <data>');
        process.exit(1);
    }
});
```

with a very basic `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "client"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "socket.io-client": "^1.4.6"
  }
}
```

Then run `npm install`, give `client` permissions to be executed and you can run it with (for example) `./client message testControl`

What do you think? ;)

Comment: Cool! Yeah this is another good way to go about it. Just create a little node server that can emit messages to my socket! Thanks!

Comment: Using `socket.send` instead of `socket.emit` fixed a problem i had

Answer (score 10):

I was able to work around this by doing the following:

1. Create a new endpoint in your server

   ```
   app.post('/sendSocketMessage', function(req, res){
     console.log("Request is "+JSON.stringify(req.body));
     socketManager.parse(req.body); //send message directly to your socket parser
     res.status(200).send("OK");
   });
   ```
2. Send data using curl

   ```
   curl --noproxy localhost, 
        -X POST 
        --data "data=testControl,loadModels,start," 
        http://localhost:8081/sendSocketMessage
   ```

Answer (score 7):

For a more low-level (socket.io-independent) solution you can use my tool [websocat](https://github.com/vi/websocat).

Example session for communicating with [socket.io's chat example](https://socket-io-chat.now.sh/):

```
$ websocat 'wss://socket-io-chat.now.sh/socket.io/?transport=websocket'
< 0{"sid":"yGVElkNCXVgc5w_JOVtc","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000}
< 40
> 2
< 3
> 42["add user", "websocat"]
< 42["login",{"numUsers":15}]
> 42["new message", "Hello from websocat"]
< 42["typing",{"username":"1223"}]
< 42["new message",{"username":"1223","message":"Reply from browser."}]
< 42["stop typing",{"username":"1223"}]
> 42["new message", "OK, may flood again."]
```

`>` denotes messages to be typed.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [iocat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iocat) cli client from npm which is based on Socket.IO.

```
$ iocat --socketio ws://127.0.0.1:8081
< Hello there
```

Comment: how to navigate to `iocat` be recognized as command ?

Comment: @Qbik what about `npx iocat`?